# Getting an error with string interpolation in Swift but I can't see any problems?

Tags: ios, string, swift, swift-playground, string-interpolation

When I'm attempting to add to an array, I interpolate a variable into the name of the dictionary that the array is nested inside of. However when I do this, I get a:

```
error: could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment'
```

I would be very grateful for any help, I'm quite new to Swift. Here is the rest of the code:

```
import UIKit

var songPlaylist : Dictionary = ["Song0" :
    ["title", "Tell Her",
    "artist", "Rizzle Kicks",
    "album", "Single - EP",
    "price", 0.69]]

func addSong(#title:String, #artist:String, #album:String,  #price:Double) {
    var numberOfSong = 0
    numberOfSong += 1
    numberOfSong

songPlaylist["Song \(numberOfSong)" =
            ["title", title,
            "artist", artist,
            "album", album,
            "price", price]];

//return songPlaylist
}

addSong(title: "Paradise", artist: "Coldplay", album: "Mylo Xyloto", price: 0.69)

println(songPlaylist)
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using an array of dictionaries?

Comment: Would that be easier? @Wain

Answer (score 0):

```
songPlaylist["Song \(numberOfSong)" =
        ["title", title,
        "artist", artist,
        "album", album,
        "price", price]];
```

This can be done when you initilaize the variable and if you replace the `=` with `:`.

Try:

```
songPlaylist["Song \(numberOfSong)"] =
        ["title", title,
        "artist", artist,
        "album", album,
        "price", price];
```

Comment: Did you mean to replace the = with a : ?